# Curl request Response code 7, could not connect to host

Tags: linux, curl, tcp, production-environment

My failover monitors service running on the same machine, with a curl request. Once in a while a single curl request got failed with response “curl: (7) couldn't connect to host”

While the service was up at that time. Also failover monitors the service after every 30 secs, but in the same interval there was no request received at application service for around 2 mins.

After receiving “curl: (7) couldn't connect to host” , failover restarted the service.

What can be the reason for failure of curl request?

Failover and service are running on same machine.

Comment: have you look at the iptables or web server logs? I guess you're using CURL to connect to monitor a webserver or something, check if there were no something slowing down the webserver response, or something in the firewall that may have stopped it.

Comment: Hi Israelss,
Thanks for your reply, there is no logs from firewall in /var/log/messages
the problem is that only a single request failed and it says service is not running on the port, It continuosly monitors using same CURL request, this is only a single instance where the request failed.